# Why does Node.js store the strings of code in the heap?

Tags: javascript, node.js

When I do a heap snapshot using node-inspector, it shows me that the second largest memory consumption is due to storing strings, mostly the Javascript code that it's running:

[image: memoryUsage]

But if V8 "[compiles JavaScript source code directly into machine code when it is first executed](https://developers.google.com/v8/design#dynamic-machine-code-generation)", why is it necessary for Node to continue storing the strings of Javascript in memory?

Couldn't it free that memory after compilation? Or is there a option to make Node discard it?

Comment: Well `.toString()` called on a function object is supposed to return the source code. I agree that it seems like a waste most of the time.

Comment: No, it can't be discarded, at least not in all cases. JavaScript can actually stringify functions and therefore needs access to their original source code. Also AFAIK V8 runs dIfferent optimizations, depending on how often a specific function is called.